# Sharing a notebook on the four color theorem applied to map of Florida

Tags: support

I want to share a Mathematica notebook to explain a problem that I'm having in applying the four color theorem to a map of Florida. My data and code exceed the limit of characters to post my question and I cannot make the content shorter. Could you please, tell me how to proceed?

Comment: You could try to post it at http://community.wolfram.com/

Comment: You could save your data and, if the code is too long by itself, the code also on one of several cloud services, and provide the link in your question.  However, readers are unlikely to examine a lengthy code in any detail.

Comment: If what you feel is a minimal description of your problem is too big to post, then your question is likely to be unsuited for this site. We really are not a free debugging service.

Comment: @ Roff Mertig:  Thank you Rolf! The Wolfram Community Forum accepts Mathematica notebooks as a vehicle to explain problems with Wolfram Language code implementation and I'm very grateful to you for sharing this information.

Comment: One other option (what I tend to be partial to) is to make a free cloud account and put your notebook there and share that link.